# Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in *.app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

I'm trying to upload iOS application to App Store using Xcode but after uploading I received next email from Apple iTunesConnect:

> Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in *.app

Are they talking about `Assets.xcassets` or what?

Anyway of course I have `Assets.xcassets` in my Xcode project with all needed icons and images I use in my app

What does it mean?

Comment: Confirm that by looking it in Build Phase > Copy Bundle Resources and if its not there add it.

Comment: @SharadChauhan yes I have it http://i105.fastpic.ru/big/2018/0515/6d/1b5c8fde8baea22119a3346384fa346d.png

Comment: It should be in blue color, better remove it and add it again.

Comment: In Build phase also. Did you remove it and add it again ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan found the reason, it was in Base.lproj folder but should be in root, so I moved Assets from Base.lproj to root

Comment: Great, put it as an answer and accept it, so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my Assets folder wasn't in the right folder (seems somehow I moved it to Base.lproj folder), it should be in root